# ADODB and SQL SERVER functions

Tags: php, sql-server, adodb

I have a web service, that connects to my MSSQL data base using ADODB for PHP. Then, I created a simple function to return a string, just for tests, but, I'll implement with another logic.

Here is my SQL SERVER FUNCTION:

```
USE [myDB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE FUNCTION [myDB].[VerifyUser]
(
    @user varchar(50),
    @pass varchar(50)
)
RETURNS varchar(32)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @token varchar(32);
    SET @token = 'Works!';

    RETURN @token;
END
```

And, this is my web service method:

```
function wseAutenticacao($usuario, $senha) {
    require_once('include/adodb5/adodb.inc.php');

    $db = &ADONewConnection('mssqlnative');
    $db->Connect(<host>, <user>, <pass>, <db_name>);
    $stmt = $db->Prepare('VerifyUser');
    $db->InParameter($stmt, $usuario, 'user');
    $db->InParameter($stmt, $senha, 'pass');
    $db->OutParameter($stmt, $token, 'token');
    $result = $db->Execute($stmt);

    return array('result' => $result);
}
```

I don't get the string "Works!" returned by my sql function. What is returned is a boolean with a false value, like I'm doing something wrong, but, I followed the ADODB Documentation example and now, I don't know what I have to do. I'm stuck!

If anyone would share your knowledge, I'll be greatful!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The @token local variable is only visible within the function itself.  The result of the scalar function needs to be assigned to the output parameter in the executed script.  One method you could try is a parameterized SELECT statement to assign the function return value to the output parameter:

```
$stmt = $db->Prepare('SELECT @token = VerifyUser(@user, @pass);');
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the thread is old, but I'm looking for a solution for something similar. It seems that the current implementation of ['mssqlnative'](https://github.com/ADOdb/ADOdb/blob/master/drivers/adodb-mssqlnative.inc.php) does not support parameters at all. That is, the base class `ADOConnection` implements a mock metod [`Parameter`](https://github.com/ADOdb/ADOdb/blob/master/adodb.inc.php#L1022) which should be overridden in subclasses. ADODB_mssqlnative does not have an override of this method, hence, your parameters disappear into the void. Next thing, the current implementaton of `_query()` expects input parameters as array. 
So, you could change your code to this to make it work

```
$db = &ADONewConnection('mssqlnative');
$db->Connect(<host>, <user>, <pass>, <db_name>);
$stmt = 'VerifyUser';
$params = array($usuario, $senha, $token);
$result = $db->Execute($stmt, $params);

return array('result' => $result);
```

Also, note that the params array is not associative. The current implementation of [`sqlsrv_query`](http://lv.php.net/sqlsrv_query) does not allow named parameters.